Meaning of lognormal in performance::check_distribution() in R
I modeled my data using lme4:lmer() function. Since the model's performance was not satisfactory, I used function performance::check_distribution() which suggested that both predicted distribution of residuals and predicted distribution of response followed the lognormal distribution.
I saw many discussions about the differences between (1) logging response value
lmer(log(Response) ~ Group*Time_point + (1|ID), data = database)

versus (2) using log link to gaussian distribution
glmer(Response ~ Group*Time_point + (1|ID), data = database, family = gaussian(link='log'))

Which lognormal interpretation should be used to follow suggestions given by performance::check_distribution()? Function performance::compare_performance suggests that the first option is much better in my case, but I would like to ensure that it is always the case.
